# Aramex API yielding "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: vb.net, web-services, aramex

I am trying to implement the [Aramex API for Tracking](http://www.aramex.com/developers/aramex-apis/42466/Shipments-Tracking-API) on my VB.NET website, but I'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
Imports TrackingReference

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _Request As New ShipmentTrackingRequest

    _Request.ClientInfo = New ClientInfo
    _Request.ClientInfo.AccountCountryCode = "JO"
    _Request.ClientInfo.AccountEntity = "AMM"
    _Request.ClientInfo.AccountNumber = "20016"
    _Request.ClientInfo.AccountPin = "331421"
    _Request.ClientInfo.UserName = "reem@reem.com"
    _Request.ClientInfo.Password = "123456789"
    _Request.ClientInfo.Version = "v1.0"

    _Request.Transaction = New Transaction

    Dim _Shipments As New List(Of String)
    _Shipments.Add("7055174991")

    _Request.Shipments = _Shipments.ToArray()

    _Request.GetLastTrackingUpdateOnly = True
    Dim _Client As New Service_1_0Client()
    Dim _response As ShipmentTrackingResponse = Nothing
    _Client.Open()
    _response = _Client.TrackShipments(_Request)

    If Not _response Is Nothing Then
        For Each _Result As KeyValuePair(Of String, TrackingResult()) In _response.TrackingResults
            Dim _trResult() As TrackingResult = _Result.Value
            For Each trR In _trResult
                Response.Write(trR.UpdateLocation & "<br>")
            Next
        Next
    End If
    _Client.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

This is my error:
[image: Server Error in '/' Application]
I have found the Aramex Developer community to be full of questions but no answers. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Did you download the sample project for vb?

Comment: Yes, but its for an APP and not a website and as such, I did not succeed in getting it to work.